# Connection refused while connecting to remote service from kubernetes pods

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, connection

I guys, I'm trying to build some services using kubernetes `1.26.3` on `Ubuntu 22.04`, which needs to connect to remote services such as SQL server, FTP server, MongoDB server.
It all used to work fine and didn't have connection problems, but recently I had to change VM ( Virtual Box Virtual Machine ) due to capacity issues and make a fresh kubernetes installation and cluster initialization, from that moment I couldn't connect to my services anymore receiving a message I can't really understand.

this is the FTP connection error I receive:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:21
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1532:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 21
}
```

This is the SQL error:

```
_fatalError: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1532:16)
        --------------------
        at Protocol._enqueue (/censor/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
        at Protocol.handshake (/censor/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
        at Connection.connect (/censor/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
        at file:///censor/src/sql/sqlConnect.js:18:8
        at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25) {
      errno: -111,
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 3306,
      fatal: true
    }
```

I don't know why it says is trying to connect to 127.0.0.1, when I clearly provide remote host using ftp setting and remote sql server:

```
let settings = {
    host: "remote host url",
    port: 21,
    user: usr,
    password: psw,
    secure: false
};

const lector= mysql.createConnection({
    host: "my remote sql server",
    user: usrl,
    password: pswl,
    database: db
});
```

Also, when i run my service locally it connects without any problem, and if I run it using only docker with "docker run ..." it also connects without problems, so I'm thinking this is a kubernetes issue I haven't faced yet.
Also my colleague to which I provided cluster installation and application deployment are not facing this problem...

Can someone help? Sorry if something is missing is the first question I post :D

I tried to run various services in kubernetes which connect to various remote services, I'm expecting a successful connection but instead I get an error with code `ECONNREFUSED`.

When I try it locally the connection is successful...